# accessing a method in another class without alloc

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have made a method player method (inherits from NSObject) that I initialize in the HelloWorldLayer class. I want to declare other methods of the same class in such a way that I don't need to alloc them. For Example:

Player.mm

```
-(id)spritePlayer:(CCLayer *)parentLayer 
                     inWorld:(b2World *)world
{
    creation of sprite body and other stuff
}
```

I want to use this method in the contact Listener class, but I've declared it the player class:

```
-(void) touchingFix:(b2Fixture *)touchedFix
{
    bodyTouched=TRUE;
    bodyFix=touchedFix;
}
```

In the Contact Listener class I can only access it through:

```
[[Player alloc] touchingFix:fixtureA];
```

Can't I access it in a way without allocating it in another method? if yes, how can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to a class method: remove the '-' in front of the method and change it to a '+'

```
+(void) touchingFix:(b2Fixture *)touchedFix
{
    bodyTouched=TRUE;
    bodyFix=touchedFix;
}
```

You can access a class method by using the class name instead of a pointer to an instance of the class:

```
[Player touchingFix:fixtureA];
```

Comment: I've changed the '-' to '+', but I am getting an error at the lines in the `touchingFix` method which say `instance variable 'bodyTouched' accessed in class variable`, also the same for `bodyFix`.

Comment: sorry, I meant "instance variable 'bodyTouched' accessed in class method"

Comment: Set the variables to be static.

Comment: sorry, I've not been on the forum for a while. I have changed the variables to static but I get an error saying "type name does not allow storage class to be specified"

Comment: You can't declare static variables inside an interface or implementation bracket-block.  Try putting them before the @interface line (but after your imports) in the .h file.  You should, however,  really think about whether these variables should be shared among all instances of the class (which is what Static variables are used for).  Maybe pass in an instance to the class method and set its properties, etc.